# 'int' object is not subscriptable for R3

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I created a for loop for to calculate the R3 as in the following coding, however, there is an error.
The error is 'int' object is not subcriptable. I checked that the size of storage a (np.shape(a) = (4,5). hence the for loop are: idn from 0 to 3 and idj from 0 to 4, which makes the shape of storage_R3 = (4,5) too.
Could anyone let me know what should I do, please?

```
import numpy as np
import random

n = 4
w = 5
v = 3

low = 0
high = 500
sample_size = 5

def get_numbers(low, high, sample_size):
    return random.sample(range(low, high), sample_size)

p_one = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)
p_two = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)
p_three = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)
p_four = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)


c_one = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)
c_two = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)
c_three = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)
c_four = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)

#Define a for SWAP
storage_a = []
for i in range(0,n):
    storage_atemp = []
    for j in range(0,sample_size):
        if p[i][j] >= c[i][j]:
            a = 1
        else:
            a = 0 
        storage_atemp.append(a)
    storage_a.append(storage_atemp)
np.shape(storage_a)

for idn in range(0,n): #------------------n-1 for the last process step, idn refers to the process steps
    
    p = [p_one, p_two, p_three, p_four]
    c = [c_one, c_two, c_three, c_four]

storage_R3 = []
for idn in range(0,n):
   for idj in range(0,sample_size):
        R3 = a[idn][idj] * p[idn][idj] + (1-a[idn][idj])* c[idn][idj] + v + 2*w
        storage_R3.append(R3)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-6dfea217881a> in <module>
      6 for idn in range(0,n):
      7    for idj in range(0,sample_size):
----> 8         R3 = a[idn][idj] * p[idn][idj] + (1-a[idn][idj])* c[idn][idj] + v + 2*w
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Strange question. In previous code you're only using `a` in middle of the loop as integer, however you're trying to use indexes for `a`.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an `integer`;

On this line it may be:

```
R3 = storage_a[idn][idj] * p[idn][idj] + (1-a[idn][idj])* c[idn][idj] + v + 2*w
```

it should be `storage_a` instead of `a`